# How to get list of valid tags of Jsoup whitelist?

Tags: java, coldfusion, jsoup

How do I get a list of all the valid tags of a given Jsoup `Whitelist`?

I can't find such a function in the docs at [Jsoup whitelist docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html). I use ColdFusion, but a java solution or hint would be fine. I guess I could translate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go the reflection route, you can do something like below which grabs access to the `tagNames` set, converts it to an array of `org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist$TagName` objects (which contain the tag names) and then appends the `toString()` values of those objects to another array.

```
<cfscript>

whitelist = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist");
collection = [];
tags = whitelist.getClass().getDeclaredField("tagNames");
tags.setAccessible(true);

// this portion uses the relaxed whitelist as an example
for (tag in tags.get(whitelist.relaxed()).toArray()) {
    arrayAppend(collection, tag.toString());
}

writeDump(collection);

</cfscript>
```

If you need the attributes and/or protocols fields, it's a similar approach but there is more to iterate through since they are maps.

Comment: Thanks a million times, Tony! I could implement all the required jsoup functionality with your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.8.1/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.java?av=f) that, what you are asking for is the `tagNames` set. The class doesn't provide any getter.

What you can do is:

1. Download the source code of jsoup and just edit the `Whitelist` class and add a getter. You can even make a pull request after that.
2. Take the default tags of each whitelist category and keep them in variables that are accessible to you.
3. The last alternative would be to use reflection in order to gain access to a private variable, but that's not a good practice, since there are other, cleaner ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Thorsten - Also FWIW, I do not know what your ultimate goal is here, but keep in mind a Whitelist involves more than just tags. It can also involve attributes, protocols, ecetera. Depending on what you are doing, that may be relevant to your app...